# ubuntu 22.04 + openvpn client = network "down"

Tags: ubuntu, routing, openvpn, ubuntu-22.04

I googled everything i was able to google, but with no success.
I will simplify my question as much as possible.

Routes before openvpn connection:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         178.xxx.xxx.xxx 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

Routes after VPN connection:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         178.xxx.xxx.xxx 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

Problem:
**after connecting to VPN -> my network is fully "broken".**

I can not ping nor openvpn server ( 10.8.0.1  ), nor google dns ( 8.8.8.8 ), nor my internet gateway ( 178.xxx.xxx.xxx ).
When i stop VPN client -> everything works again.

Do you have any idea how to fix that?
Thanks.

ip route show ( before VPN connection = network works ):

```
ip route show
default via 178.xxx.xxx.xxx dev enp5s0 proto static onlink
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

ip route show ( after VPN connection = network does not work at all ):

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
default via 178.xxx.xxx.xxx dev enp5s0 proto static onlink
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

ifconfig enp5s0 ( interface with internet access )

```
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 178.xxx.xxx.xxx  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 2a01:xxx:xxx:xxx::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::xxx:xxx:xxx:c860  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a0:36:bc:ca:c8:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 110506  bytes 18354128 (18.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 117994  bytes 17466604 (17.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x81c00000-81cfffff
```

VPN client logs ( connection established, but dropped later due to no networking ):

```
May 30 16:54:35 client openvpn3-service-logger[20691]: {tag:5238658794065795403} Adding IP Adress 10.8.0.2/24 gw 10.8.0.1 ipv6: no
May 30 16:54:35 client openvpn3-service-logger[20691]: {tag:5238658794065795403} Setting remote IP address to 195.xxx.xxx.xxx ipv6: no
May 30 16:54:35 client openvpn3-service-logger[20691]: {tag:17752863769272376516} Connected: 195.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194 (195.xxx.xxx.xxx) via /TCPv4 on tun/10.8.0.2/ gw=[10.8.0.1/]
```

VPN server logs ( same situation ):

```
May 30 16:54:34 server ovpn-server[62795]: 178.xxx.xxx.xxx:41434 [client] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]178.xxx.xxx.xxx:41434
May 30 16:54:34 server ovpn-server[62795]: client/178.xxx.xxx.xxx:41434 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.2, IPv6=(Not enabled)
May 30 16:54:34 server ovpn-server[62795]: client/178.xxx.xxx.xxx:41434 MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.2 -> client/178.xxx.xxx.xxx:41434
May 30 16:54:34 server ovpn-server[62795]: client/178.xxx.xxx.xxx:41434 MULTI: primary virtual IP for client/178.xxx.xxx.xxx:41434: 10.8.0.2
...
May 30 16:54:48 server ovpn-server[62795]: client/178.xxx.xxx.xxx:41434 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
```

/etc/openvpn/server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_au1Yf0HuxvBTSYQS.crt
key server_au1Yf0HuxvBTSYQS.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

.ovpn:

```
client
proto tcp-client
remote 195.xxx.xxx.xxx
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_au1Yf0HuxvBTSYQS name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
#ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
```

Comment: Please provide config file, and any logs from the client and server

Comment: @Tom i added more info, but i believe its not very helpful as problem with local routing, not VPN server configuration.